# HttpClient и прокси

Tags: c#

Как в этом соединении использовать http прокси ?
при это есть логин и пароль

```
    async Task<string> Load(string uri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var res = await client.GetStringAsync(uri); // асинхронная загрузка
            return res;
        }
    }
```

То что пробовал делать сам.

```
    async Task Load(string uri)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy("ip:port"),
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password"),
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var res = await client.GetStringAsync(uri); // асинхронная загрузка
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: В теории, выглядит правильно. Как проверяли, работает или нет?

Comment: @Monk сначала пробую с передачей handler в HttpClient , потом без

Comment: @Monk с handler не получаю результат, без handler всё работает как надо

Comment: Но это как раз ожидаемый результат, особенно в случае, когда прокси не отдает ничего. Если прокся живая, то я бы проверял на каком нибудь 2ip или ещё чем нибудь какой внешний IP виден.

Comment: @Monk прокся живая - почему то заработало таким образом, но я не понял почему xD
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856543/httpclient-and-using-proxy-constantly-getting-407